# How does God undo destiny when one surrenders?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, karma, ramana-maharshi

Whether it is the Gita or saints like Ramakrishna, Shirdi Sai Baba and Ramana Maharshi, surrender is described as the ultimate means of undoing or coping with destiny.

My question is, how does God undo destiny when one surrenders? Isn't it the same as going against his own rules of karma?

Some references:

> Bhagavad Gita: Chapter 18, Verse 66: Abandon all varieties of dharmas and simply surrender unto me alone. I shall liberate you from all sinful reactions; do not fear.

Ramana Maharshi:

> M.: “All right. What need be said has been said. Well. What is destiny? There is no destiny. Surrender, and all will be well. Throw all the responsibility on God. Do not bear the burden yourself. What can destiny do to you then?”
>
> D.: Surrender is impossible.
>
> M.: Yes. Complete surrender is impossible in the beginning. Partial surrender is certainly possible for all. In course of time that will lead to complete surrender. Well, if surrender is impossible, what can be done? There is no peace of mind. You are helpless to bring it about. It can be done only by surrender.
>
> D.: Partial surrender – well – can it undo destiny?
>
> M.: Oh, yes! It can.
>
> D.: Is not destiny due to past karma?
>
> M.: If one is surrendered to God, God will look to it.
>
> D.: This being God’s dispensation, how does God undo it?
>
> M.: All are in Him only.
>
> (Source: Talks with Sri Ramana Maharshi, Talk 244)

Comment: See Gita 18.58 and 18.65-66

Comment: Why should the godhead "undo destiny"? This doesn't make any sense to me.